# Общий текстовой чат на php

Tags: php, mysqli

Пишу чат на php, при попытке залогиниться, в сессию записывается `user_id`, после успешной попытки, появляется страница чата, где написаны все сообщения(т.к чат общий), но дело в том, что мне выводятся все сообщения написаны якобы мной, хотя некоторые сообщения были написаны другими юзерами с другими email.В чем может быть проблема? Вот код логина:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';
    if (isset($_POST['email-e']) && isset($_POST['password-pass'])) { 
    $email_e = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['email-e']);
    $password_pass = crypt($_POST['password-pass']);

    $query = "SELECT id, email, password FROM users_data WHERE email = '$email_e' AND password = '$password_pass'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['email-e'] = $row['email'];

    setcookie("CookieMy", $row['email'], time()+60*60*24*10);
  }
    else {
        echo 'Пользователь не найден!';
      header("Location: login.html"); 
    }
  }
    if (isset($_SESSION['email-e'])){
     header("Location: chat.php");
    } else {
    $email_e = '';
    if (isset($_COOKIE['CookieMy'])){
        $email_e = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['CookieMy']);
    }
}
?>
```

А вот код самого чата:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db_chat.php';
// header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//echo trim($_SESSION['email-e'])." <br />"."Вы авторизованы <br />";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Chat</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Chat</title>
<style>
form,p,span{margin:0;padding:0}
    input{font:12px arial}
    a{color:#00f;text-decoration:none}
    a:hover{text-decoration:underline}
    #wrapper,
    #loginform{margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:25px;background:#ebf4fb;width:504px;border:1px solid #acd8f0}#loginform{padding-top:18px}#loginform p{margin:5px}
    #chatbox{text-align:left;margin:0 auto;margin-bottom:25px;padding:10px;background:#fff;height:270px;width:430px;border:1px solid #acd8f0;overflow:auto}
    #usermsg{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:395px;
        border:1px solid #acd8f0
    }
    #submit{width:60px}
    .error{color:#f00}
    #menu{padding:12.5px 25px 12.5px 25px}
    .welcome{float:left}
    .logout{float:right}
    .msgln{margin:0 0 2px 0}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome,<?php echo trim($_SESSION['email-e'])?><b></b></p>
        <p class="logout" name="logout">
            <a name="logout" id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a>
        </p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chatbox">
        <?php
if(isset($_POST['submitmsg'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['usermsg']) && is_string($_POST['usermsg'])) {
        $usermsg = trim($_POST['usermsg']);
        $sql_chat ="INSERT INTO `users_chat` (usermsg)(user_id)
                    VALUES('{$usermsg}','{$user_id}')";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli_chat,$sql_chat);
    } 
}
        $query_chat = "SELECT * FROM `users_chat`";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli_chat,$query_chat);
        while($row_chat = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo "Email: ".$_SESSION['email-e']."<br>\n";
        echo "Message: ".$row_chat['usermsg']."<br>\n";
        //echo date('Y.m.d H:i',$row_chat['time']);
}
?>
    </div>
<form  name="message"   action="" method="post">
<input name="usermsg"   type="text"   id="usermsg"/ style="margin: 0 auto;">
<input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send"/><br>
</form>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

С БД все в порядке, все работает и записывается, но показывается только email юзера, который залогинился и все сообщения якобы от его имени,а нудно всех, кто писал и какое писал сообщение.

Comment: Как минимум уберите md5 и поставьте (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php). Проверьте что записывается в сессию ну и соответственно ваше условие.

Comment: @Дмитрий убрал, записывается user_id

Comment: md5 на запись не влияет, а влияет на обеспечение безопасности.

Comment: @Дмитрий да,спасибо

Comment: Не могу по коду найти где вы пишете поля (ид пользователя написавшего сообщение и текст сообщения). Насколько я понимаю вы пишете только текст $sql_chat ="INSERT INTO `users_chat` (usermsg) VALUES('{$usermsg}')";

Comment: @Дмитрий  я исправил, посмотрите пожалуйста. Но у меня так тоже не работало.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема из-за того, что email автора берётся из сессии, а судя по коду, в сессии хранится email авторизованного пользователя. По идее email нужно брать из `$row_chat['email-e']`

Так же было бы неплохо использовать изолирование от HTML для вывода сообщений ([дока](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php))

UPD
Пример изолирования от HTML:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitmsg'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['usermsg']) && is_string($_POST['usermsg'])) {
        $usermsg = trim($_POST['usermsg']);
        $sql_chat ="INSERT INTO `users_chat` (usermsg)
                    VALUES('{$usermsg}')";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli_chat,$sql_chat);
    } 
}
        $query_chat = "SELECT * FROM `users_chat`";
        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli_chat,$query_chat);
        while($row_chat = mysqli_fetch_array($res)):?>

        Email: <?=$row_chat['email-e']?> <br>
        Message: <?=$row_chat['usermsg']?> <br>
<?php endwhile;
```

Comment: можете показать на примере? Я не совсем понимаю

Comment: Привёл пример изолирования +исправил ошибку

Comment: спасибо. Только вот, там не выходят мейлы тех, кто писал другие сообщения. А вместо  этого просто пустая строка. Можете это тоже объяснить? Спасибо

Comment: Запрос на выборку неправильный, нужно связать таблицу с сообщениями с таблицей пользователей по id

Comment: а что я делаю не так? я же записываю $user_id в сессию.

Comment: Если в таблице сообщений хранится id сообщения, id пользователя и текст сообщения, то ты не сможешь вытащить из этой таблицы почту) Нужно в запросе на выборку сообщений связать таблицу (INNER JOIN) с сообщениями и таблицу с пользователями по id пользователя

Comment: вот я сделал так в консоли phpmyadmin в таблице users_chat, он объединил их, но не сработало: SELECT * 
FROM users_chat INNER JOIN users_data 
ON users_chat.user_id = users_data.id;

Comment: А если в селекте вместо звёздочки написать `users_data.email-e AS email-e, users_chat.usermsg AS usermsg`?

Comment: ошибку выдает. не знаю в чем проблема. такую ошибку выдает  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: Тогда советую научиться дебажить и  гуглить ошибки